# How to compare two DATETIMEs from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date-parsing

I want to limit my users to only (be able to) post something every 15 minutes.

So in my SQL query I select `NOW()` to get the current date and time, and also the user's last post date `date_added`. I want to compare the two dates and if the difference between `now()` and `date_added` is less than 15 minutes, then the user cannot yet post. If it's greater then he can. If less than 15 minutes then I'd like a message like 'Please wait x minutes and y seconds.' So I need some kind of date manipulation/comparison.

How should I approach this. In MySQL or PHP?

Comment: search this site. This has been asked  ad nauseum.

Comment: Look into `date_sub` or `date_add` in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL: [`DATE_ADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) or [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub), then compare.

In PHP: [`DateTime->diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Answer (score 2):

You could simply convert the mysql timestamp into a php-date and compare from there
$time = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", $mysqltime);

You will find lots of useful snippets how to compare dates on the functions documentation: http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

Edit: pozs anwser nails it ...

Answer (score 1):

Something like

`SELECT count(*) FROM posts WHERE last_post > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 minute);`